# Monit: ubuntu проверка соединения mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, monit

Нашел в интернете "скрипт" для проверки статуса сервиса mysql + проверка соединения. Но по какой то причине monit выдает статус "**Connection failed**". Хотя во всех примерах, что я находил в интернете описывается именно такой пример проверки соединения через monit. Логин/пасс естественно рабочие. Может все такие делается как то по другому, либо надо что то дополнительно прописывать?

```
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    group mysql
    start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
        if failed 
            port 3306
            protocol mysql username "LOGIN" password "PASSWORD" then restart
        if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Comment: А файлы `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` и `/etc/init.d/mysql` существуют? и `start`, `stop` пашут? А то на свежей бубунте балом правит systemd и наверное надо уже под него рецепты пилить. Он кстати вполне себе неплохо отдаёт статус работы проги.

Comment: don Rumata, Они существуют, иначе бы монит не стартовал совсем. Ну под него рецепты не видел.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем хз почем так, но проверяет соединение монит только при стандартной конфигурации конфига без логина и пароля и по стандартному порту. Т.е. если у вас mysql запущен на отдельном порту (как у меня было) все равно нужно писать стандартный..
Т.е. выглядит вот так:

```
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
        start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
        restart program = "/etc/init.d/mysql restart"
                if failed
                        host localhost
                        port 3306
                        protocol mysql
                then restart
                if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Comment: Такс.. А вообщем не работало изначально как я написал, потому что я неправильно настроил конфиг самого мускула (my.cnf)0. Не были прописаны пункты "socket" и "port" для [mysqld] и для [client] и для [mysqld_safe] не был указан сокет. Ну я только учусь)